# In KITTI dataset, why is it required to divide np.asarray(PIL.Image.open(img_path)) by 256 to get groundtruth depth map?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lidar, disparity-mapping, kitti

I don't know if I'm stupid in asking this question.

But, I'm unable to reason why in the [*** CODE ***](https://github.com/nianticlabs/monodepth2/issues/101#issuecomment-550055146) written by [VictorCVision](https://github.com/VictorCVision), the np.array is divided by 256 to get the `depth_map`?

Also, what is the unit of depth (is it meter ?) in case of these projected groundtruth PNG files.
(Ex: KITTI_dataset/2011_09_26/2011_09_26_drive_0001_sync/proj_depth/groundtruth/image_02/0000000005.png)

I'm looking for correct explanation for my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a correct answer to my question. Please see this [link](https://github.com/nianticlabs/monodepth2/issues/101#issuecomment-1582428267).

Comment: Please don't post links as answers. Instead you can post the answer along with the link as supporting information.